Saving complex json (Postman request body) as is in Mongodb as document
I am trying to save the request body (complex json ) that is being posted from Postman and save as it is in Mongodb using Mongodb C# driver. I have several of these complex jsons that are being sent from Postman and I need to store them as is.
{"data": {
"type": "sometype",
"headers": {
    "host": "aboce.com",
    "port": "80"
},
"innerdata": {
    "a": [
        "arrayvalue1",
        "array1value2"
    ],
    "d": {
        "DictionaryKey1": "dicValue1",
        "DictionaryKey2": "dicValue2",
        "DictionaryKey3": "dicValue3"
    },
    "ad": [
        {
            "DictionaryKey1": "dicValue1",
            "DictionaryKey2": "dicValue2",
            "DictionaryKey3": "dicValue3"
        },
        {
            "DictionaryKey1": "dicValue1",
            "DictionaryKey2": "dicValue2",
            "DictionaryKey3": "dicValue3"
        }
    ],
    "dd": {
        "DictionaryKey1": {
            "DictionaryKey11": "dicValue11",
            "DictionaryKey12": "dicValue12",
            "DictionaryKey13": "dicValue13"
        }
    },
    "ddd": {
        "DictionaryKey1": {
            "DictionaryKey11": {
                "DictionaryKey111": "dicValue111",
                "DictionaryKey112": "dicValue112",
                "DictionaryKey113": "dicValue113"
            }
        }
    },
    "add": [
        {
            "DictionaryKey1": {
                "DictionaryKey111": "dicValue111",
                "DictionaryKey112": "dicValue112",
                "DictionaryKey113": "dicValue113"
            }
        }
    ],
    "addd": [
        {
            "DictionaryKey1": {
                "DictionaryKey111": {
                    "DictionaryKey111": "dicValue111",
                    "DictionaryKey112": "dicValue112",
                    "DictionaryKey113": "dicValue113"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "adad": [
        {
            "DictionaryKey1": [
                {
                    "DictionaryKey111": "dicValue111",
                    "DictionaryKey112": "dicValue112",
                    "DictionaryKey113": "dicValue113"
                },
                {
                    "DictionaryKey111": "dicValue111",
                    "DictionaryKey112": "dicValue112",
                    "DictionaryKey113": "dicValue113"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"host": "something.com"

}}
Tried to capture the json from Postman as JsonElement and save it to Mongodb. This is not successful as it is only storing empty json brackets
public JsonElement? data { get; set; } = new JsonElement();
await _mongodbCollection.InsertOneAsync(data);
However, it saves data as
data{}
Is there a simple and easier way to save the json into MongoDB using c# driver.
Tried the MongoDB C# driver latest version but it does not work in any of the ways of jsondocument, bsondocument, etc.

Possibly duplicate: Dotnet API Error Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
